# difference between subscribe(store) and dispatch?

Tags: ngrx, ngrx-effects

For this effect,

```
@Effect()
triggerOtherAction$: Observable<Action> = this.actions$
  .ofType(SOME_ACTION)
  .do(() => console.log("This line works for both"))
  .map(() => new OtherAction())
```

When I dispatch an action, I can think these two ways

first,

```
Observable.of(new SomeAction()).subscribe(this.store);
```

second,

```
this.store.dispatch(new SomeAction());
```

what is the difference between above two lines? For the first one, it doesn't trigger other action, but execute the line of do() and reducer works well.

Comment: What version of `@ngrx/store` are you using? The behaviour you've described should only be effected by the current master.

Comment: @cartant npm latest version. but, I checked the source code. store.subscribe and store.next are same.

Answer (score 3):

There is no reason to dispatch actions using code like this:

```ts
Observable.of(new SomeAction()).subscribe(this.store);
```

In fact, there is a good reason not to: the observable to which the `store` is subscribing will complete and that will see the `store` complete, too.

In version 2.2.1 of `@ngrx/store`, that's not a problem - as its implementation of [`complete`](https://github.com/ngrx/store/blob/v2.2.1/src/store.ts#L47-L49) does nothing - but with the current master, [`complete` is implemented](https://github.com/ngrx/store/blob/master/src/store.ts#L69-L71) and dispatching an action as above will see the store complete and no further actions will be dispatched.